# 4-digit password that have exactly 2 digits in common with a given password.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

**Question:** A system generates a 4 unique digits password. Extracting 2 passwords created independently and randomly, what is the probability that they have exactly 2 digits in common?

**My attempt:**
There are $\frac{10!}{(10-4)!} = 5040 $ different passwords in the sample space. If we take one them, say $2647$,  there are ${4 \choose 2} = 6$ cases of coincidence: $\{2,6\},\{2,4\},\{2,7\},\{6,4\},\{6,7\},\{4,7\}$. So, if we consider the first case, there are 30 passwords that have a 2 and a 6 and also don't have a 4 and a 7. If we shuffle the digits, we still get valid passwords, so in the first case there are $30 \times 4! = 720$ passwords. The reasoning for the other cases is identical, so we must have $720 \times 6$ passwords in total that match the given password in exatcly 2 digits. So the probability asked is $\frac{720 \times 6}{5040} = \frac{6}{7}$

**the supposed answer is $\frac{3}{7}$**

What did I miss? Thanks in advance.

Comment: should be 15, not 30 passwords that have a 2 and 6 but not 4 and 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are counting, for example, permutations of $\{2,6,3,8\}$ and permutations of $\{2,6,8,3\}$

Having found $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to choose two common digits, you should have found $\binom{6}{2}$ ways to choose other distinct digits. Since you don't care about the order of the digits, you should divide by $\binom{10}{4}$ to arrive at the given answer.

$$\frac{\binom{4}{2}\binom{6}{2}}{\binom{10}{4}}=\frac{3}{7}$$

Answer (score 1):

There are $^{10}P_{4}$ unique-digit passwords.

Given a password, say $3927$, let's find out how many other passwords have the digits $2$ and $7$. There are $^4C_2$ ways $2$ and $7$ can be arranged. That leaves us with $2$ slots that need to be filled in. These $2$ slots can be filled in with $8 \times 7 = 56$.

The number of other passwords that match the password $3927$, in the sense they have exactly $2$ digits in common = $^4C_2 \times 56 = 336$. This works for any $4$ digit password.

You might have to do this: $336 - 1 = 335$

The number $45$ may play a role.

*Cogito* ... *non liquet*

Answer (score 0):

The term  **independently** is very important, because selecting one password will not reduce the number of elements in sample space. So assume that  we randomly select an password among $10 \times 9 \times 8 \times 7 =5040$.

Assume that our random element element is $abcd$, now we will select the second element , so the question is that what is the probability that the second selected element would have exactly two common digits with $abcd$.

Now, lets select which digits can be same with $C(4,2)$. Assume that we select  $a,c$. Then those can be placed $4 \times 3 $ ways in any four digits.

The rest two digits can be placed $6 \times 5 $ ways among the rest six elements.

So $$\frac{6 \times 12 \times 30}{5040}= 3/7$$